# How to overlay unicode characters on image with node-canvas?

Tags: node.js, canvas, unicode, node-canvas

I'm trying to overlay unicode characters on an image, but the characters are not showing.

```
   var img = new Image()
   img.src = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'images', 'snow.jpg'))
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 500, 500)

   img = new Image()
   //img.src = canvas.toBuffer()
   ctx.font = "40pt Calibri";
   ctx.lineWidth = 1
   ctx.strokeStyle = '#ddd'

   ctx.fillStyle = '#000'
   ctx.fillText('Wahoo', 49, 99)
   ctx.rotate(0.5)
   ctx.translate(20, -40)
   ctx.fillText("Testing", 100, 180)
   ctx.rotate(0)
   ctx.translate(20, -60)
   // Unicode here
   ctx.fillText('\u5929\u6c23', 160, 100)

   canvas.createPNGStream().pipe(res);`
```

Comment: I would imagine you'd need a font that contains glyphs for the characters U+5929 `天` and U+6C23 `氣`, which Calibri does not.

Comment: It works when use canvas as an element and render in html.  However it is not working when generate the image programmatically using canvas.createPNGStream().

Answer (score 0):

Maybe replace
`ctx.strokeText = "#ddd"`
by
`ctx.fillText = "#ddd"`

It may work better and correcly display...